# Ubuntu 17.10 doesn't boot after installation in VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-3, display-manager

[image]

I have also switched to command interpreter mode by hitting (Ctrl-Alt-F2) and installed all the updates that had been published after the installation. But it still doesn't work. I am stuck here for now.

How to I resolve this?